# ui-select doesn't expand input field in multiple tags selection

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/36IRP9J079vjWFIFjRSb?p=preview) I have a ui-select with multiple tagging. It works fine - I couldn't replicate the problem in plunk. The problem in my application is that the bottom border doesn't expand when the tags occupy more than one line. This is a picture of the behavior I get (again, not in the plunk):

[image]

I updated the version of ui-select to the latest. What could be the problem?

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

});

app.directive('selectColors', function () {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = true;

    directive.templateUrl = 'selcols.html';

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.availableColors = ['Red','Green','Blue','Yellow','Magenta',
                                   'Maroon','Umbra','Turquoise'];

        scope.singleDemo = {};
        scope.singleDemo.color = '';
        scope.multipleDemo = {};
        scope.multipleDemo.colors = ['Blue','Red'];

    };

    return directive;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the class form-control had a fixed height. Removing it fixed the problem

```
.form-control {
height: 28px !important;
}
```